# DS FixtureAdapter error Undefined for Ember JS

Tags: html, ember.js, ember-data

I keep getting DS.FixtureAdapter Undefined error. I am Not sure how to fix this error. I am getting the error on the line with App.PersonAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});

Here is app.js code.

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here

});



App.PersonAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});

App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
firstName: DS.attr(),
lastName: DS.attr(),
age: DS.attr()

});
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('person');
  }
});
App.Person.FIXTURES = [
{
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    age: 39
},

{
    id: 2,
    firstName: 'Jane',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    age: 29
}
]
```

index.html for ember js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">

    <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <li>{{item.firstName}} - {{item.lastName}} is of age {{item.age}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>

  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-template-compiler-1.10.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.10.0.debug.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>



  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <!-- to activate the test runner, add the "?test" query string parameter -->
  <script src="tests/runner.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DS.FixtureAdapter` is not part of `ember.js` You need to include `ember-data.js` which is still in beta and needs to be downloaded from [here](http://emberjs.com/builds/#/beta).

Working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/satofo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: well, it's obviously not seeing that include... Otherwise, there is no reason for it not to work as I showed in my working example

Comment: before I poseted the question I  included the ember-data.js it is in my code above still not working I downloaded the beta

Comment: looks like I am using the wrong one I will use the one you have posted